# dwm - session polkit

Tags: window-manager, session, dwm, polkit

I am really struggling to get the session polkit to work.
I am not really familiar with how it works, but I have been using gnome before switching to dwm and in gnome it worked perfectly, so I wanted to replicate that.
First of all: As I understood it, the polkit is responsible for giving momentary privilege escalation to the user, by prompting him for the root password.
Is this correct?
How can I replicate that behavior without a DE but with a WM like dwm?

Comment: It depends if you use a DM (display manager) or you run eg. `startx`. If you use simple DM or `startx` you probably want to check `dbus-launch` man page. Plus every distro does it in different way, if you use a DM you probably need to read some Xsession-like startup script. For example in Void Linux, lightdm while using i3wm should run `~/.xprofile`, but in OpenSUSE they don't load it, they use `~/.xinitrc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use dwm as well, I have in a .xinitrc file, with a polkit to start at login.  I use the xfce-polkit.

```
/usr/lib/xfce-polkit/xfce-polkit &
```

As an example I also use Thunar as my file manager and have a custom action that calls a root session of Thunar using `pkexec`.

Using the polkit will give you the same DE behaviour with dwm.

Comment: Using Linux Mint it was easier to install lxpolkit from the package repositories. I couldn't compile xfce-polkit due to dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your question. I also use `dwm`, to be able to use polkit programs like `pkexec` as far as I know the `dbus-daemon` must run first. According to the documentation, `polkitd` does not need to be run manually. So there is no need to worry about it.

> polkitd provides the org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 D-Bus service on the
> system message bus. Users or administrators should never need to start
> this daemon as it will be automatically started by dbus-daemon(1) or
> systemd(1) whenever an application calls into the service.

Source: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkitd.8.html